# How to create bootable iso from VirtualBox machine?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, virtualbox, live-usb, bootable

I've got Debian or Ubuntu system installed inside VirtualBox. I adjusted it to my demands: I installed some software, uninstalled unwanted packages, configured the settings for some user account and prepared a desktop with shortcuts for it.

Now, what I would like to do is to convert this virtualbox system into .iso file that could be deployed on bootable USB stick to make it LiveUSB system with all my settings preserved.

I don't want to create bootable USB stick per se. For this purpose I hope to use the software I recently discovered, which is [Ventoy](http://www.ventoy.net). It allows to boot .iso files by simply copying them onto USB stick and it seems to be quite reliable. The problem is how to convert my system with all its settings into .iso file. I spent a lot of time on testing tools like Respin, PinguyBuilder, LinuxLiveKit or SystemBack. None of them works like I imagined. To be honest, most of these software seem to be abandoned and, for me, does not work at all.

I also experimented with VBoxManage clonehd but this creates some horrendous 50GB img files while vdi is only 20 GB, and I believe that even after my configuration the iso file shouldn't be much bigger than standard Debian/Ubuntu LiveUSB iso (I didn't install many new packages in my system).

Is there any easy way to achieve my aim or the only hope is to build my own distro?

Comment: There are some issues with what you are attempting to do:1.First, `/dev` `/sys` and `/proc` are always created on the fly as they are tailored to the system on which they boot.so no use in copying them in their current form 2.Some hardcoded configurations in `/etc` would also fail on any new system with a different configuration, and would likely push you into a recovery shell on boot (missing NIC cards for example, wrong video drivers), so these also need some consideration.  Could you explain why LinuxLiveKit was not what you were looking for, as I had good experience with it in the past.

Comment: I've just made an ISO with the help of LinuxLiveKit to test it once again. Booting it ends up with "Failed to load ldlinux.c32".

Comment: Have you tried formatting the USB with FAT(or FAT16) and not FAT32. This is related to your BIOS not being able to see it, and more to do with how you put the iso on the USB and not the image you create

Comment: The problem is that my iso file is bigger than 4GB, so I formatted USB with NTFS, next I used https://www.rmprepusb.com to make a bootable USB. BTW. just today I realized that the disk I created for my virtualbox machine was dynamically resizable.  I heard that it might be another cause of my problem. I'll think I need to convert it to fixed size and try again.